# Alluvial Charts - Fluxo não aparece

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho uma tabela como essa:

```
Organization    Timeframe   Code                    id
1   Agencia1    Fortnight 1 International Affairs   1
2   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Environment             2
3   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Health                  4
4   Agencia2    Fortnight 1 Public Policy           5
5   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Politics                6
6   Agencia2    Fortnight 2 Disaster                7
7   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Public Policy           8
8   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Federal Government      9
9   Agencia1    Fortnight 2 Business                10
10  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Federal Government      11
11  Agencia2    Fortnight 3 Dissemination - COVID19 12
12  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Transparency - COVID19  13
13  Agencia2    Fortnight 3 Economy - COVID19       14
14  Agencia1    Fortnight 3 Prevention - COVID19    15
15  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Economy                 16
16  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Media                   17
17  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Leisure                 18
18  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Politics                19
19  Agencia1    Fortnight 4 Prevention - COVID19    20
20  Agencia1    Fortnight 5 Prevention - COVID19    21
```

Eu gostaria de fazer um alluvial chart que mostrasse os diferentes tópicos de cada organização em cada quinzena (Fortnight). Eu criei um gráfico com o que gostaria, mas os fluxos que ligaria (com uma cor para cada organização) não estou aparecendo. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image]

O código do que fiz é esse:

```
alluvial_data <- as.data.frame(FC_Outlets %>%select(Organization, Timeframe, Code))
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% mutate(id = row_number())

#Remove duplicates
alluvial_data <- alluvial_data %>% 
  distinct(Organization, Timeframe, Code, .keep_all = TRUE)


# Convert Timeframe to Factor - Categorical Variable
alluvial_data$Timeframe <-as.factor(alluvial_data$Timeframe)

# Convert Code to String
alluvial_data$Code <-as.character(alluvial_data$Code)

library(RColorBrewer)

# Define the number of colors you want
nb.cols <- 10
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols)


# Chart
ggplot(alluvial_data,
       aes(x = Timeframe, stratum = Code, alluvium = id,
           fill = Code, label = Code)) +
  #scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set2") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycolors) +
  geom_flow(stat = "alluvium", lode.guidance = "frontback",
            color = "darkgray") +
  geom_stratum() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Organizations")
```

Obrigado

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.